# What is a web service stack?

Tags: java, web-services, jboss

What is a web service stack?

Recently I am having trouble understanding all these terms like JBossWS native stack and JBossWS CXF stack and all.

Can anyone please explain me this terms?

Answer (score 0):

A web service is an interface written with a specific language that exposes your app functionalities on web and can be used by any application that can reach it .

It is a class (written used a framework like JAX-WS or Apache-CFX stack) that generates an XML Based interface (SOAP) exposed on a specific url address. All the external applications (written in all known languages) can invoke this interface to execute the exposed functionality.

The WS is platform independent. So, if you decide to refactor your code or pass from java to C# for example, mantaining the same WS interface all the other external applications can continue to invoke it in the same identical way without change anything.

Sorry for my english :)

thake a look at this article if you want to try your very first Web Service implementation
https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/websvc/jax-ws.html